# Como alterar o texto dentro da Caixa de Texto no Word usando VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-word

Estou tentando mudar o texto dentro da Caixa de Texto do Word. Não estou usando nenhuma ActiveX para isso, é a caixa de texto normal do Word mesmo. Como eu faço isso programando pelo VBA?

Eu consigo fazer alterações nos textos normais que escrevo pelo Word, mas quando o texto está dentro de uma Caixa de Texto, não consigo alterá-lo por este método.
Eu fiz assim para mudar os textos normais:

```
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
     .Text = "Estado Civil"
     .Forward = True
     .Execute
     .Replacement.Text = "###"
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
    End With
```

Eu procurei por várias documentações e tutoriais e não achei nada.
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá. Uma forma de fazer é acedendo à coleção de objetos "shapes" que existem no documento, mas atenção que existem algumas "shapes" que não suportam esta propriedade, logo tens de testar o tipo de objeto. Para isso podes usar a propriedade `HasText`.

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Novo Texto"
```

Comment: Muito muito muito obrigado!!!!!!

Comment: Olá a melhor forma de agradecer é validar aa reposta. Ainda bem que ajudou

Comment: Acho que consegui validar, eu não sei usar ainda direito o Stackoverflow